# How to Save and Load a Sklearn Model in Different Files

Tags: python, scikit-learn

Is there any possible way to train a model in a different file with a different list and use prediction with another list? This does not work because vectorizer is not defined. I do not want to re train the data every time I run my program. Is it possible to save the model and just load the model in another file and predict the data with another list?

```py
document = df.stack().tolist()

vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(stop_words='english')
X = vectorizer.fit_transform(document)

true_k = 20
model = KMeans(n_clusters=true_k, init='k-means++', max_iter=100, n_init=1)
model.fit(X)

joblib.dump(model, 'model.joblib')
```

```py
model = joblib.load('model.joblib')

documentnew = df.stack().tolist()


print("\n")
print("Prediction")

X = vectorizer.transform([documentnew[2]])
predicted = model.predict(X)
```

When I load the model and I transform the documentnew, i get this error.

```
ValueError: Incorrect number of features. Got 7 features, expected 39
```

The approach above works if its in the same file, but I dont want the model to change and train everytime I run the program.

Comment: What line does the error occur on? `predicted = model.predict(X)` on the new data?

Comment: Yes, if only I am using it in separate files.

Comment: The k-means model is fit on a dataset with 39 features. When you pass in new data there are only 7 features. Do you re-fit the `TfidfVectorizer`?

Comment: Yes, else it says vectorizer does not exist here : ```X = vectorizer.transform([documentnew[2]])```.

Comment: Try saving the vectorizer and loading it in the other file